# Find both teams finishing positions even if they retire?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sheet:

[image]

Where for each Constructor there are two cars, so in Column C I use:

```
=MINIFS(G:G,F:F,A2)
```

to find the best finishing car, which seems to work fine.

For the second car I tried in column D:

```
=MAXIFS(G:G,F:F,A2)
```

Hoping that would simply find the other cars results, unfortunately it seems that if the other car retires from the race the max just picks up the first car still.

Is it possible to detect the retired cars and return R?

Thanks again...

Comment: "R" is not a number so will not be picked up by min or max. Perhaps try adding a COUNTIFS.

Comment: Or a simple `IF`. Because if max equals min, means they have to have retired. Simply because no car can finish at the exact same position. e.g: `IF(MAXIFS(G:G,F:F,A2)=C2,"R",MAXIFS(G:G,F:F,A2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have got access to ExcelO365 with it's `FILTER` function you could use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(G:G,F:F=A2))
```

If this is unordered, then you can also use `SORT` which will put potential `R` values at the end:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER(G:G,F:F=A2)))
```

[image]

<sup>Screenshot showing above formula in `C2` and dragged down.</sup>

---

If you don't have ExcelO365, you could follow up on my comment which stated:

> *"Or a simple IF. Because if max equals min, means they have to have retired. Simply because no car can finish at the exact same position. e.g:"*

```
=IF(MAXIFS(G:G,F:F,A2)=C2,"R",MAXIFS(G:G,F:F,A2))
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution would be: (confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$6,SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$6=$A2,$F$1:$F$6),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

or as non-array

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,($F$1:$F$6)/($E$1:$E$6=$A2),COLUMN(A1))),"-")
```

[image]

You can pull the formula right and down.